# Profiling C code R

Tags: c, r

I am very new to R, but not new to C. I am having a look to see if I can speed up a package for a friend. Usually with C I would compile an application with the -pg flag set and then pass gprof the gmon.out file.

I tried turning the library in to a stand-alone application but there are too many dependencies all tied up inside R (utilities and even some strange fortran library) so abandoned that path.

I have also edited ~/.R/Makevars to include -pg. but that doesn't seem to produce a gmon.out file anywhere that I can find.

[This thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2006-February/036581.html) seems to be the location of the most information, but I'm not finding it very helpful (perhaps because it's 10 years old). I tried to get oprofile up and running but failed.

Please could somone point me in the right direction?

TL;DR: How do I profile C code in an R package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [u/bc2zb](https://www.reddit.com/user/bc2zb) over on reddit for pointing me towards [this presentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/ismNov2009introHPCwithR.pdf).

So the answer is as follows:

- Write some test code as an r script.
- Install libgoogle-perftools-dev and google-perftools
- Run code thus: LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libprofiler.so.0" CPUPROFILE=/tmp/rprof.log r testCode.R (may need to be su - or just change the output to ~/somefolder instead)
- Then run: google-pprof --cum --text /usr/bin/r /tmp/rprof.log | less